# SQL Returned values length .NET C#

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

In the following sample of code I call a stored procedure and get back a dataset that I store in var newstorevalue:

```
var newstorevalue = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(acf.AcConn(), "sp_selectbyname", valuetosend);
```

How can I "see" and store how many records are returned? For ex. I want to print a message that says:"Procedure returned X records"

I am new in development. Any help is welcome!

Comment: `string myMsg = "Procedure returned " +  newstorevalue.Tables[0].Rows.Count + " records";`

Comment: @Fred That works for me. In case to print the returned value in UI (via Angular for ex) I created the following code:
       payload.valuesreturned = newstorevalue.Tables[0].Rows.Count; But what do i need to place in return statement? return what?? (dummy question)

Comment: Show us the function code

Comment: @Fred       `public ActionResult NameNumberResult(ItemEventNameDTO payload)
        {
            var valuetosend = payload.itemname;
            var acf = new AcFunctions();
            var newstorevalue = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(acf.AcConn(), "sp_selectbyname", valuetosend);
            payload.valuesreturned = newstorevalue.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            return ???;
        }`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but i suppose your spHelper.ExecuteDataset should return a DataSet ?

If I'm correct, so you should have the response here :

```
var count = newstorevalue.Datatables[0].Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

The most trivial way is to get the value of newstorevalue.Tables[0].Rows.Count

You didn't specify which database is (I suppose Oracle). In this case you can try to get the value with the function

> SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(...)

reading the (number) result of a query that uses the Oracle Table function:

> select count(*) from table(sp_selectbyname(*parameter*));

try this in a sql console first.. *should* work.

Bye.

Mario.

Comment: Why would you make another call to the database?

Comment: I don't know the specific use case.. the call to executescalar may be executed *instead of* the call to executedataset. I proposed two different solutions..